# Return email address from Sheet2 after matching entries in Sheet1 and Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I'd like to send a mail to multiple recipients based on this situation:

Sheet1 contains different records (by row)

- In column H, initials of a user

There may be the same recipient for different records. This whole Sheet1 must be sent to the recipients.

Sheet2 contains

- In column A, the same initials of the user as Sheet1
- In column B, the email address.

Based on Sheet1 and the initials of all users, I want to send to the address found on Sheet2. This is this part I'm struggling with.

Here is a part of my code:

```
Sub test_mail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
Dim sTo As String
Set emailRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B6") // not dynamic at all because will be changed each time..
For Each cl In emailRng
    sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
Next
sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = sTo
    .CC = "person1@email.com;person2@email.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "SS failed to load
    .Body = "Dear user," 
    .Attachment = // How to put directly sheet 1 ??
    .Display
End With
```

I was thinking about removing the duplicates in column H of Sheet1 to get the list and associate this with a v-look up to get email addresses from Sheet2. But I'm sure there's an easier way.

Comment: Using the above code, I think you'd need to do somewhat more complicated -- since you can only *attach* a file (not a worksheet, unless that worksheet has been dumped to a temporary file), export the worksheet as its own file, and then attach the file. see [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail2.htm).

Comment: Seems long and complicated this code, will try if I can find something easier. Any ideas on my initial request? thanks :)

Comment: Fortunately, all the code is already written :)  *This whole Sheet1 must be sent to the recipients* -- you can't do that without exporting the sheet to file, then attach the file. Not sure what you mean by "my initial request" -- if you're asking about your VLOOKUP, then maybe you should try it rather than just "thinking about removing duplicates" -- do something, see if it works, if not, then clarify your specific problem statement in the question :)